# Converting between the two types of generic functions in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to convert between these two kinds of generic function:

```js
type Foo=<S>(a: S) => S
type FooReturnType = ReturnType<Foo>          // unknown

type Bar<S> = {
  (a: S): S
}
type BarReturnType = ReturnType<Bar<string>>  // string
```

I.e. convert from type `Foo` to type `Bar`, and `Bar` to `Foo`?

When one defines a function with generics is takes the form of type `Foo`.  However when passing the return type type around, it is much more useful if it takes the form of `Bar`.

One solution is to define the return type separately, using generics, and then to use that in one's function.  However this splits one's code, and makes it messier.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what do you mean

Comment: @captain-yossarian when one defines a generic function e.g. `function<S>(a:S){ return S}` it always takes the form `<S>(a: S) => S` and if one wants to use the generic return type, there is no simply way to access it via e.g. `Foo<string>`

Comment: This isn't directly possible in TypeScript at the type level; to get close to this you need to drop down to the value level and use [instantiation expressions](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) or [higher order inference from generic functions](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions), as shown [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/NlDgxN).  Does that fully address your question?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, thank you - that's the solution!  I didn't know one could do `typeof foo<S>`.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way purely at the type level to convert between [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types and generic call signatures.  The scope of the generic type parameters are different, and although there is a logical relationship between them, this relationship cannot be properly expressed in the type system.  For that to happen we'd probably need true *higher kinded types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), or possibly *generic values* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574), or possibly *existentially quantified generics* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).  And we don't have direct support for any of those (as of TS5.0).

---

The language does have some limited ability to represent this sort of thing, but it all involves dropping down to the value level.  That is, you need to have a *value* of the relevant type, and then you can perform some operation on that value to compute something that has the type you want.  Depending on your use cases, this sort of value-level code might be sufficient.

For example, [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) let you convert a specific type representing a generic call signature (like `Foo`) into a generic type representing a specific call signature (like `Bar`), but you need a *value* of type `Foo` (or you need to at least *pretend* to have such a value):

```
type Foo = <S>(a: S) => S
type Bar<S> = (a: S) => S 

declare const foo: Foo;
type BarFromFoo<S> = typeof foo<S>; // instantiation expression
// type BarFromFoo<S> = (a: S) => S
```

And you can use [higher order type inference from generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) to take a generic type like `Bar<S>` and convert it to `Foo`, but you need to have (or pretend to have) a *value* of a type related to `Bar`:

```
declare const bar: <S>() => Bar<S>;
```

And you need to have a function that shuttles around arguments and return types:

```
declare const funWithFunctions: <A extends any[], B extends any[], R>(
    f: (...a: A) => (...b: B) => R
) => (...ab: [...A, ...B]) => R // higher order generic function inference
```

And then operate on the former with the latter and get its type:

```
const fooFromBar = funWithFunctions(bar)
type FooFromBar = typeof fooFromBar;
// type FooFromBar = <S>(a: S) => S
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAeAygPgBQEMBcU6AlMpkQFCiRQBCuAThuSgN5R6EldQC+FFACYQAxgBtG0EXAB2AZ2BQAZgkLw4Abirho9BjAZwAtuubIo1CHCXKEzDVAD0jqAEt5wXDOCvcP2VAQAB5gDBBycq6yFM4WOnSMBsamWOacRKRI5OgCwuKSUNIeUABGjITM2JnkevZCohJhhbIKygCuMgDqrsAAFjAdIv7yFQCCgUHAEDKCclBeIADaALoANHQTUzNzCyvrAEo4FFAnyoTYAHRXBFCj1RxXFyWEtPf7FPeX189Qi4+j60etGWb1ivVcAHNehAGFA4AxhLCIdMYa4RO0ZEMojI3DIlDDpiIIBQiq0VHAkkY9OYlB1un0BpjhnJsGUGMRtDR1JTqShLNZbBTDFTGFpYpZYAgeYxzJUbiQyEQgA)